# Python - Iterate thourhg all available pages of a API connection

Tags: python, api, bybit

I am currently trying to develop my own "automated" trading journal. I get the data from the bybit api (https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-introduction) I use the pybit (https://github.com/verata-veritatis/pybit) lib to connect to the bybit API.
I am trying to pull the closed p&l positions (https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-closedprofitandloss)

I was able to connect to the bybit API via some python code.

Now let me describe the problem I am having:
The API request is limited to **50 results PER PAGE**.

**How can I iterate through all the pages and save this in ONE JSON file?**

This is the code I am currently using:

```
import pybit as pybit

from pybit import inverse_perpetual
session_unauth = inverse_perpetual.HTTP(
    endpoint="https://api-testnet.bybit.com"
)

session_auth = inverse_perpetual.HTTP(
    endpoint="https://api.bybit.com",
    api_key="",
    api_secret=""

)
data = session_auth.closed_profit_and_loss(symbol="BTCUSD", limit=50)

import json
with open('journal.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

import pandas as pd
df  = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\journal.json")
df.to_csv (r"C:\Users\Work\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\journal.csv", index = None)
```

I left the api_key and api_secret empty because this is confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with pagination there is a parameter one can use to tell the server or API in your case to give you the next N items.

By visiting the [link you provided](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-closedprofitandloss) to the API documentation, one can spot there is a parameter called `page` which is an integer you can send along with the request. This is again limited to 50 pages, after that you might try to play with `start_time` or `end_time` which I suspect could provide access to even older records.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
I noticed that. I am trying to save all pages in one Json file. For analysis purposes.
I need to iterate through all the pages and save this in one file